# Java Messaging Service - message not getting received

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, jms, glassfish-3

I am writing a program using NetBeans IDE and Java EE with glassfish3 server.  Currently I have 2 threads, A and B.  They both are sending messages back and forth between eachother.  The issue I am having is this:

```
1.  A sends a message, M1, to B
2.  B receives M1
3.  B sends M2 to A
4.  A hangs waiting on M2
```

Here is my code:

Thread A:

```
//required declarations
producer = session.createProducer(AtoBQueue);
m1 = session.createMapMessage();
m1.setString("m1", "m1Val");
m1.setJMSReplyTo(BtoAQueue);
flag = true;
producer.send(m1);

consumer = session.createConsumer(BtoAQueue);
connection.start();

if(flag){
   m2 = (MapMessage) consumer.receive();
   String m2Val = m2.getString("m2");
   if(m2Val.equals("true")){
      flag2 = true;
   }
}
...
```

Thread B:

```
consumer = session.createConsumer(AtoBQueue);
connection.start();
while(true){
   m1 = (MapMessage) consumer.receive();
   m1Val = m1.getString("m1");
   if(m1Val != null){
      flag = true;
   }

   MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer((Queue m1.getJMSReplyTo());
   m2 = session.createMapMessage();
   if(m1Val != null){
      if(m1Val.equals("m1Val")){
         m2.setString("m2", "m2Val");
         m2.setJMSReplyTo(AtoBQueue);
         producer.send(m2);
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add in a session.commit() after I do a producer.send(message) only for Thread B.

Answer (score 0):

Your Thread A sends the key as "report" and you expect in Thread B as "m1", hence it doesn't send the reply back to the Queue. Also try creating the Consumer in A before you send the message.

Comment: oh whoops. I changed it to m1.  I had simplified my code a little and had accidentially left that in there.  That is not my issue though.  The problem I am having is with A not receiving m2